# Laravel Migration deletes the record and the refresh it

Tags: php, powershell, laravel-4, database-migration

I have created a table using migration and schema. I also added a field. then several records were inserted into the database. I understood that I forgot to add a column. I added a line in my Schema `$table->string('activation', 256);` and then in PowerShell I executed the following command to update the table:

```
php artisan migrate
```

it updated the table, but also deleted the records, what should I do to skip deletion of the records while updating the table. The following is the Schema:

```
Schema::create('users', function($table)
        {
                       $table->increments('id'); // incremental index
                       $table->string('username', 256); // username
                       $table->string('password', 256); // password
                       $table->string('name', 512); // full name of the user
                       $table->string('email', 512); // email address
                       $table->string('finding', 512); // the way the site found by the user
                       $table->string('mobile', 24); // the mobile number
                       $table->string('date', 256); // UNIX timestamp [saves in VARCHART to prevent any truncation
                       $table->string('birthday', 64); // birthday saved in dd-mm-yyyy format
                       $table->string('sex', 24); // saved in Persian characters male or female
                       $table->string('activation_code', 256);
                       $table->integer('activation_status');                       
                       $table->integer('newsletter'); // Boolean :: 0 -> no 1-> yes
                       $table->integer('province'); // the id of the province (corresponds to table.provinces)
                       $table->integer('city'); // the id of the city (corresponds to table.city)                       
                       $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no flaw there. You're just using it incorrectly.

You need to create a table, you do:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_table_users
```

Then you create your schema:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id'); // incremental index
        $table->string('username', 256); // username
        $table->string('password', 256);
        ...
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

The the method `up` is to migrate and the method `down` is to rollback the migration, it will drop your table.

Then you do

```
php artisan migrate
```

If you do again:

```
php artisan migrate
```

It will not work, because that migration is already migrated, to succeed in a second migrate you must:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

The rollback command will execute the `down` method, which will, in this case, DROP your table.

If you just need to add a new column to your table you have to:

```
php artisan migrate:make add_column_to_users_table
```

And add

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->string('activation', 256);
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->dropColumn('activation');
    });
}
```

And then you`ll be able to run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Again.

If migrate somehow deleted your records or table is because you've ran the wrong command.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add/edit/delete something from a migration after you have run it you should add another migration file.
Some additional documentation for Laravel 4: 
http://laravel.com/docs/schema
http://laravel.com/docs/migrations

Comment: Not really, migrations are made so that you can use them in teams (in combination with something like git). When you would add a column in a table and I (for example) pull in your code I can easily see what you changed and migrate your additional column without losing all of my data